# how to solve the psycopg2 and pillow installation problem on cpanel (

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, cpanel, psycopg2

for hours I have been trying to deploy my django project on cpanel of lws, I created a python application and activated the virtual environment but as soon as I try to install the dependencies I receive an error

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [143 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/Pillow.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'PIL._imaging' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/Tk
declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF-DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.1\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/uloyxtlb/virtualenv/core/Ulc_loyola_core/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_imaging.o
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
  Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-ext)" -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=80420 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/home/uloyxtlb/virtualenv/core/Ulc_loyola_core/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.

      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2-binary
Failed to build Pillow psycopg2-binary
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, psycopg2-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projec
```

I tried to install psycog2-binary and some sudo commands like `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev or sudo yum install postgresql-devel`
but none work, all sudo commands cannot be found

Comment: "on cpanel of lws"?

Comment: AKX yes it's the lws cpanel

Comment: t looks like you need root permissions to install this software and you don't have them. You might be able to work around this by creating a virtual environment and installing your requirements there. Otherwise you will need to ask the server administrator to grant you the required permissions, or to install the requirements for you.

Comment: What is "the lws cpanel"?